# How to clear huge area in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What I'm trying to do here is clear a massive area in my world. I can use the fill command with air but that is limited to so many blocks. So what I was wondering is if there is a line of code I could put in a command block that would allow it to "climb". So it would execute with the fill command at (x100 y01 z100 x900 y01 z900) and then it would change to (x100 y02 z100 x900 y02 z900 and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

you can make an armor stand:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"Bob\""}
```

then make it clear around itself, using an always active repeating command block:

```
execute at @e[name=Bob] run fill ~-100 ~ ~-100 ~5 ~100 ~100 air
```

then send it into space:

```
/effect give @e[name=Bob] minecraft:levitation 10 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [WorldEdit](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit), with which you can select and remove massive areas with a single command.